# how to delete lines using tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I am making a program in python using tkinter and I need a canvas object to delete after a second but I don't know what function to use and I can't find it here is my code:

```
def click(event):
    canvas.create_line(event.x, event.y, coords)
    canvas.after(1000,canvas.delete)

canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>',click)
```

when I call this the lines just stay there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an item on a canvas, tkinter will return a unique identifier. Simply save the identifier, and use it as a parameter to `canvas.delete`.

```
def click(event):
    canvas_id = canvas.create_line(event.x, event.y, coords)
    canvas.after(1000, canvas.delete, canvas_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `canvas.delete(the variable)` like:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Canvas
app = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(Screen, width=800, height=400)
canvas.pack()

Boom = canvas.create_line(200, 10, 200, 500)

Button(text="Click to del the line",font=("arial",10),bg="black",command=del_line).pack()

def del_line():
    canvas.delete(Boom)

app.mainloop()
```

and That's it.